# How do I install the driver of Medaitek RT3070 in Debian Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, drivers, compiling

I didn't understand the build instructions and the "**make**" command returns errors:

```
┌──(**mohammedmehditber㉿DESKTOP-U9KKGTJ**)-[**~/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3**
_20121022] 
└─**$** sudo make **&&** sudo make install 
make -C tools 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mohammedmehditber/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxS
TA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools' 
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mohammedmehditber/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxST
A_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools' 
/home/mohammedmehditber/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools/bin
2h 
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/mohammedmehditber/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_
2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/Makefile 
make -C /lib/modules/5.10.0-kali9-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/home/mohammedmehditber/Do
wnloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux modules 
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-amd64' 
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common/Makefile:225: =============== ERROR =
============= 
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common/Makefile:226: 'SUBDIRS' was removed i
n Linux 5.3 
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common/Makefile:227: Use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXT
MOD=' instead 
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common/Makefile:228: =======================
============= 
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common/Makefile:229: *** .. Stop. 
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common/Makefile:185: __sub-mak
e] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-amd64' 
make: *** [Makefile:389: LINUX] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you're asking how to install a driver intended for an old 2.6.xx kernel version to your Kali Linux that uses a kernel version 5.10.xx?

The answer is, **you don't install that**, it's way too old. It's like trying to use an old 32-bit Windows XP driver with a new 64-bit Windows 10: it's not supported and very likely not going to work.

The `make` command is even telling you that the build process has changed since the development of that old driver, and that's just the first of many reasons why this will not work:

```
=============== ERROR ============== 
'SUBDIRS' was removed in Linux 5.3 
Use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD=' instead 
==================================== 
*** .. Stop.
```

Even the structure of the kernel Makefiles that control the driver build process has changed between the development of that driver and your current kernel.

The standard kernel should already include a suitable driver... but there's one thing that makes the correct driver less obvious. A "Mediatek RT3070" is actually **Ralink RT3070**, rebranded because Ralink the company was bought by Mediatek. Linux still uses the original company name, because the driver was developed before the rebranding happened.

https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:148f-3070

According to the link above, that USB WiFi adapter should work using the `rt2800usb` driver module, which should be already included in your default kernel. This driver requires a firmware file for the adapter: it should be in package `firmware-misc-nonfree`, so you should make sure that package is installed. There might also be a `firmware-realtek` package, which may or may not be just a dummy transitional package that automatically pulls in `firmware-misc-nonfree`.

If your package manager has `firmware-realtek` available, install it too, just to be sure.

Comment: The driver you mentioned rt2800usb is installed it, but It doesn't support AP Mode, that's why I tried to install the original given by the Medatek website.

Comment: `rt2800usb` seems to be a mac80211 driver, so it would certainly work in AP mode with [`hostapd`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/hostapd). And it seems [that's how other people are using it with a RT3070.](https://community.toradex.com/t/how-to-set-up-a-soft-access-point-under-linux-using-a-wlan-usb-dongle-based-on-the-ralink-rt3070-chipset/4529) (note, this is from year 2016; current Kali definitely has `hostapd` packaged). If you're trying to do something like `iwconfig <wireless interface> mode master`, that's the old way of doing AP things that no longer works.

Comment: I tried to use create_ap but it shows me this:
https://i.imgur.com/Pb9PHCj.png

Comment: `ERROR: your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and be an AP at the same time.` That looks pretty clear to me. If you need this system to be an AP that is also wirelessly connected to another AP, then you'll need either two RT3070s or a more capable WiFi adapter that can run two modes simultaneously. Two RT3070s might actually be the more flexible option, as with two separate adapters you can freely choose the radio channels to use for each, while a single multi-mode adapter might be restricted to using the same channel for both modes.

Comment: If you want this system to be just an AP without an internet uplink, you should use the `-n` option with `create_ap` and omit the second interface name.

Comment: But It is written in the physical package that is supports AP Mode, and it works on Windows after enabling AP Mode BW20.

Comment: Here are the details https://i.imgur.com/7LyFyvi.jpg

Comment: [Here's a link.](https://www.szedup.com/product-item/1500mbps-wifi-adapter-high-power-outdoor/#tab-id-2-active) Nothing here or in your image makes any promises about working in AP mode, much less about connecting to another AP **while being an AP for other clients**. If it worked in Windows in AP mode and that Windows system also had a wired connection, it probably used that as an uplink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128151/discussion-between-mohammed-mehdi-tber-and-telcom).